# Documentation algorithm topic

Tags: discussion, documentation

So far there has been a lot of broad topics for things like "searching" and "sorting", where examples being posted are specific algorithms for searching or sorting.  The number of searching and sorting algorithms is way beyond what would ever be considered a reasonable number of examples.

**Proposal: specific algorithms and data structures are topics within the algorithm tag.  Examples are specific either specific implementations of algorithms (lang impls) or visualizations highlighting specific properties of the data structure (e.g. a complete binary tree vs a deep one).**

I'd love to just own the tag and edit everything to fit this pattern, but I'd like to have some sort of consensus on it first and a nice place to link to explaining the approach.

Thoughts?

Comment: I only expect to see pseudocode in [algorithms] Docs.  We don't need to duplicate, say, the [Rosetta Code page on insertion sort](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Comment: How many examples do we want to have for every (search) algorithm? I have sympathies for only pseudocode.